# Applying a jQuery event to multiple classes on a page

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a few divs for which I wrote a script to adjust the height of it appropriately.  Each div contains 2 divs in it and a small script is written to calculate the highest of these divs and lines them up correctly.  The problem is that all the divs on the page are now assigned the same height.  I would like it to calculate separately for each div.

HTML

```
  <article>
   <div class="inner-content-container equalHeight">
      some text....
   </div>
   <div class="entry-sidebar equalHeight"> some text...</div>
  </article>
  <article>
   <div class="inner-content-container equalHeight">
      some text....
   </div>
   <div class="entry-sidebar equalHeight"> some text...</div>
  </article>
  <article>
   <div class="inner-content-container equalHeight">
      some text....
   </div>
   <div class="entry-sidebar equalHeight"> some text...</div>
  </article>
```

jQuery

```
   var highestCol2 = Math.max(jQuery('.entry-sidebar').height(),jQuery('.inner-content-container').height());
   jQuery('.equalHeight', this).height(highestCol2);
```

Comment: you're not being clear here

Comment: You can use a callback function where you've got `this` in your jQuery call to specify a function that will affect each selected element individually. How you calculate the height individually is up to you. Please provide a fiddle if you want any further help.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  I have multiple article divs who's height needs to be adjusted depending on the content inside it.  At the moment the script is making all the article divs on the page the same height instead of calculating each one individually.

Comment: did you do the script on load or it's being called from somewhere?

Comment: I'm confused here. Why not move the `height:` CSS restriction and instead use something like `min-height:`, then the div will grow naturally to the content within it, width restrictions given of course.

Comment: I think you need to add the height of the 2 div's instead of finding the max of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function to get a callback for each article and use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to find only the element inside the current article and use it like this

```
$('article').each(function() {
    var $article = $(this);
    var highestCol = Math.max($article.children('.entry-sidebar').height(),$article.children('.inner-content-container').height());
    $article.children('.equalHeight').height(highestCol);
});
```

here's the working example in [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9ksvw/1/)

Answer (score 1):

It is because using `height()` as a getter method on a set of elements will return the height of the first element in the list.

So try

```
jQuery('article').height(function (i, height) {
    return Math.max(jQuery(this).find('.entry-sidebar').height(), jQuery(this).find('.inner-content-container').height());
})
```